# Linking to Boost from Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker

I want to compile an Xcode (version 4.5.2.) project using Boost-library. I have successfully installed Boost on my mac and I got the following message:

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
XXX/boost_1_52_0
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
XXX/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib
```

How do I add a compiler include path and a linker library path in Xcode? Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I should mention the following is for Xcode 4.5.2. You should likely mention which version of Xcode you're using in your question.

1. In the Project Navigator select your project file (usually at the top)
2. Given the two view choices of Basic or All, choose All in the view pane.
3. Locate the **Search Paths** section in the settings list
4. Locate the **Header Search Paths** subsection under Search Paths
5. Add the path (absolute or relative to the source folder). You can do it for Debug, Release, or Both.

And in case you didn't see it, you can add addition library search paths here as well, same area, subsection **Library Search Paths**

---

**Updated for Xcode 5.0.2**

1. In the Project Navigator select your project file (usually at the top)
2. In the right pane is the project configuration panel. Toward the top-left are two sets of selectable radio options. One says Basic or All, choose **All**. The second says Combined or Levels, choose **Combined**.
3. Locate the **Search Paths** section in the settings list
4. Locate the **Header Search Paths** subsection under Search Paths
5. Add the path (absolute or relative to the source folder). You can do it for Debug, Release, or Both.

Comment: Thank You very much for your clear and precise answer! This saved me probably another day of trial-and-error navigating in Xcode :) By googling I knew where to look for these settings, but my problem was that I was in "Basic" view, so Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths were not visible and I was desperately looking for an option to add those.